# How to Iterate inside an iteration work for JSONobject in Java

Tags: java, android, json

I have a `JSONobject` And am using `keys()` method to iterate over it. but I need to iterate over the values too to being able to catch every part of the value ,, here is how my JSON object ((named `Station`)) looks like:

```
        {
           "key_1" : {
                     "value_1" : "value_1_data",
                     "value_2" : "value_2_data", }
                },
           "Key_2": {
                    "value_1" : "value_1_data",
                    "value_2" : "value_2_data", }
                   }
        }
```

I'm using this method to iterate over it :

```java
        Iterator<String> iter = Station.keys();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            String key = iter.next();
            try {
                Object value = Station.get(key);
                Log.e("the key: ", key);
                Log.e("the value: ", String.valueOf(value));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // Something went wrong!
            }
        }
```

Now I need to loop through the `value` again to be able to catch every item in the value part >> `value_1` and `value_2` .

Comment: `JSONObject` has several different `get()` method variants. Use the appropriate one, not the generic `get()`.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Am asking because am not sure what is the `appropriate` one.

Comment: What's the type of value under `key_1`? That'd be the appropriate accessor method.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov `Key_1`, `value_1` and `value_2` are `String` , but `value_1_data` and `value_2_data` are `double`

Comment: No they're not. The value under `key_1` is an object itself. The value under `value_1` is String.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov that means I should be looping through `key_1`. trying a for loop there gives me this `foreach not applicable to type "Java.lang.String"`

Comment: You should loop through **value** under `key_1`, not the key itself. Keys are always strings in JSON.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov `foreach not applicable to type "Java.lang.Object`

Comment: Did you miss me saying you should not use generic `get()` from the start of this comment chain?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov will be super useful..  if you showed an example.

Comment: If example from below isn't enough, you will need to expand on your question, as I don't understand what is it that you want to do: you seem to be talking about object keys as if they were values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this logic:

```
Iterator<String> keys = idObj.keys();

while (keys.hasNext()) {
      String key = keys.next();
      if (idObj.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {

            Iterator<String> idObjkeys = idObj.getJSONObject(key).keys();

            while (idObjkeys.hasNext()) {
                 String subkey = idObjkeys.next();

            }
      }

      if (idObj.getJSONObject(key).get(subkey) instanceof String) {}

    }
```

**Above logic can be used!**